# show Cordova plugins search results in command line

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

As of the new update of Cordova to 6.0.0 from last Thursday the command `cordova plugin search whateverSearchTerm` results in a new browser window opening to show me the search results on their web page instead of writing a list to the command line.

I used to show the output of the command in a Java application. So now I don't get a String from the command but instead the browser opens and the user can't just choose from a list of plugins.

So my question is: How do I get the list of plugins being put out as a String in my command line instead of a browser opening? I know I could somehow try to parse the page shown in browser but that seems kinda like an overkill to me. I hope someone can help me on this issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `npm search` command

Example

```
npm search cordova camera
```

Or you can use the `cordova-plugins` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugins) that search plugins on plugreg.com and http://registry.cordova.io/

Install it with

```
npm install -g cordova-plugins
```

And use it with

```
cordova-plugins search camera
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugins

Comment: any tips on how to get the cmd output of `npm search cordova camera` in a more computer readable way? It's being written like a table but separated by whitespaces which makes it kinda unnerving to parse. Appreciate any ideas.